# Why am I getting "gapi is not defined" when I try to use Google API from Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey userscript?

Tags: google-api, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, google-sheets-api

I am hoping to access Google spreadsheet (which requires authentication) to add some data to the portal I use. Since I don't have access to the server itself, I wanted to do it using Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey userscript (I would like to share this userscript with other users of the portal too as I believe this is very helpful feature but the portal is no longer developed).

However I can't get the Quickstart example from Google page to work (https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/js#troubleshooting).

```
window.onLoadCallback = function(){
.. javascript code from quickstart guide with my client ID..
}};

var str = .. html code from quickstart guide ..

$("html").html(strVar);
```

I have tried to use window.onLoadCallback as suggested by other answers but it does not help.

I am using Client ID for application type "Other". Any idea where I am making a mistake or how to approach this differently? I am not the owner of the spreadsheet nor the owner of the server.

Comment: Which part of your HTML code did you place the onload call to <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth"> ? I think what's happening is that your making a call to the Google API library but it's not loaded yet.

Comment: Why do you replace the complete page instead of writing an own html page? There might be a problem with Greasemonkey's sandbox context. You can work in site's context by enclosing all your code into single quotes and passing it as a string source to `setTimeout()` with a zero delay time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [External dependency not defined, even though it was loaded with @require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74946942/external-dependency-not-defined-even-though-it-was-loaded-with-require)