# External dependency not defined, even though it was loaded with @require

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

I am trying to install and use sweetalert2 in Tampermonkey but I am getting:

> Swal is undefined

in the console.

I tried to use `@require` and `/* globals Swal */` but it didn't work.

[image: console error]

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Quizlet Explanations Get Answer
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://quizlet.com/explanations/questions/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=quizlet.com
// @require      https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.6.16/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

/* global Swal */

window.onload = function() {
    Swal.fire(
        'Good job!',
        'You clicked the button!',
        'success'
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>sweetalert2 example</title>
</head>

<body>

  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      Swal.fire({
        title: 'Good job!',
        text: 'You clicked the button!',
        type: 'success',
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Link it to this URL instead [**https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11**](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11)

```
// @require      https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11
```

As [double-beep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10607772/double-beep) has mentioned [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74958708) you need to:

> **Enable sandbox mode** by adding `// @unwrap` to the headers

and leave it empty.

```
// @unwrap
```

Then call your modal like this:

```
/* global Swal */

window.onload = function() {
                Swal.fire({
                title: 'Good job!',
                text: 'You clicked the button!',
                type: 'success',
            });
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Notice these lines of code from [the lib's source on GitHub](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/blob/91147e9c2f67c3e4195f573619d82fec944c54e7/rollup.config.js#L14-L16):

> ```
> if (typeof this !== 'undefined' && this.Sweetalert2) {
>     this.swal = this.sweetAlert = this.Swal = this.SweetAlert = this.Sweetalert2
> }
> ```

There are two solutions:

1. **Use `Sweetalert2`** which is exposed by the JavaScript file in any case.
2. **Enable sandbox mode** by adding `// @unwrap` to the headers. While the loader injects the script into the page, the script lives in the sandbox, which is disabled if `@grant` is `none`. With `// @unwrap`, you can achieve the desired `this` behaviour and use any of the exposed `swal`, `sweetAlert`, `Swal`, `SweetAlert` names.